# Erlang gen_fsm transition to a new state

Tags: erlang, fsm

I have erlang gen_fsm, my first state:

```
begin({Nick}, _From, State) ->
            {reply, true, next_state, State}.
```

Then i have:

```
next_state(_Event, _From, State) -> 
        io:format("Test \n"),
        {reply, ok, begin, State}.
```

But i don't seen `Test` note in shell

How correctly transit to a new state?

Comment: There's an error in that code (missing comma after the call to `io:format/1`). Was that a mistake when copying or is your code just not compiled?

Comment: Yes, i edit in stackoverflow, in code all right.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, ensure  that *begin* is the actual **initial state** of your FSM. You specify the initial state of your FSM by returning, in your *init* function, something like:

```
{ok, begin, State}
```

Where *begin* is your initial state.

Also, note that you're defining a `Module:StateName/3` function, which will be called any time a `gen_fsm:sync_send_event` is performed on your FSM. If you're trying to send events to the FSM using `gen_fsm:send_event`, you should instead define a function `Module:StateName/2`, which is its asynchronous version.

Finally, try to debug your modules by [tracing](http://aloiroberto.wordpress.com/2009/02/23/tracing-erlang-functions/) them, rather than adding printouts. It's much simpler and it avoids you recompiling your code time after time.

More information are avilable [here](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/gen_fsm.html).

Answer (score 2):

you may find some examples here:

http://spawnlink.com/articles/an-introduction-to-gen_fsm-erlybanks-atm/index.html

and here:

http://pdincau.wordpress.com/2010/09/07/an-introduction-to-gen_fsm-behaviour/

Hope it helps